# Is there a way to to allow webforms accept case sensitive keys?

Tags: webforms

I've been using the webform module for Drupal 8, and initially it appears as though the webform submission handlers only send through submission keys as all lowercase.

Is there any way to get around this? I need case sensitive keys in order for the webform submissions to interface with another platform, which is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

For that you may have to create handler and activate that handler after the webform submission, get the keys as a simple text field perform the hash operation on it and then save to database. webform supports this - [image]